# SQL asterisk(*) all possible uses

Tags: sql

I have a simple question. I want to list down all the scenarios where we can use the keyword asterisk(or star) *.

I am known of only these scenarios:

```
Select * from Customers;
Select Count(*) from Customers;
Select Customers.quantity * Customers.price from Customers;
```

I've searched all over the internet but didn't find any other use case.

Also, the scenarios where we can use * with a column in select query.

**Edit**: Ok as @Lucas Eder requested to know my use-case, here it is. I've got a program which accepts SQL query and store it in DB. Before storing, it does a validation not allow to create `select *` and `Count(*)` queries. Other than that it should allow all other queries. So that's the reason I want to know other scenarios where `*` is used so that I can whitelist them.

Comment: Never forget the old way to do outer joins in SQL Server, using `*=`

Comment: @LukasEder: but that's SQL Server specific, not "SQL"

Comment: Row pattern quantifier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Mandatory https://xkcd.com/927

Comment: @LukasEder: then you need to include all Postgres operators using a `*` as well: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6f67f4b24da62248bb8ca9cbff7c24b6

Comment: @LukasEder that syntax is not supported in SQL Server for a long time now... If memory serves, 2000 was the last version that supported it.... Some memories are better left buried.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'll let you answer that postgreSQL operators part. I had already added the Oracle number data type in my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fun question!

Here's what [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) knows about the various SQL dialects (looking at its sources):

**Repeating yours (with some comments):**

```sql
-- Unqualified asterisk
SELECT * FROM t;

-- Unqualified asterisk with useful Google BigQuery extension
SELECT * EXCEPT (a, b) FROM t

-- Asterisk in COUNT
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t;

-- Multiplication operator for numbers
SELECT a * b FROM t;

-- Multiplication operator for intervals / numbers
SELECT INTERVAL 1 DAY * 3 FROM t;
```

**Other cases jOOQ knows:**

```sql
-- Qualified asterisk
SELECT t.* FROM t;

-- Multiline comment syntax
SELECT /* important column */ a FROM t;

-- Oracle hint syntax
SELECT /*+FIRST_ROWS*/ a FROM t;

-- Old SQL Server outer join syntax (no longer supported)
SELECT * FROM t, u WHERE t *= u;

-- Oracle precision / scale wildcard
CREATE TABLE t (a NUMBER(*), b NUMBER(*, 2));

-- PostgreSQL syntax for case insensitive pattern matching (ILIKE) 
-- (there are many more operators)
SELECT 'abc' ~~* 'A%'
```

**Other cases I know:**

```sql
-- MATCH_RECOGNIZE pattern matching
SELECT * FROM t MATCH_RECOGNIZE ( ... PATTERN X Y* Z ... )

-- Oracle 21c's projecting everything into JSON
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(*) FROM t
```

**String literal contents, which are specified and parsed as well:**

```sql
-- Regular expressions (the asterisk is in a string literal, but it's still worth noting)
SELECT regexp_replace(a, 'a*', '') FROM t;

-- Similar predicate (again, it's in a string literal but the format is specified)
SELECT 'abc' SIMILAR TO 'a*'

-- JSON Path contents (there are quite a few possible asterisks here)
SELECT JSON_QUERY(col, '$.*') FROM t;

-- XPath contents
SELECT XMLQUERY('/x/*' PASSING t.xmldoc) FROM t
```

**Esoteric cases**:

The ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E) SQL standard specifies in 21.6 <embedded SQL Fortran program> [sic!]

> <Fortran type specification> ::=
> CHARACTER [ <asterisk> <character length> ] [ CHARACTER SET
> [ IS ] <character set specification> ]

Yes. You asked for it!

Comment: Thanks, @LukasEder! I also want to know is there any alternative solution for multiplying columns with * ?

Comment: Yes, `a*b` is the same thing as `e^(ln(a)+ln(b))`, for positive numbers `a` and `b`. But that's quite a different question.

Comment: We have a specific use case to avoid `*`. We can use this as well `(a/(1/b))`, it will work for negative numbers as well.

Comment: @aniket_777: OK, but you really have to explain this use-case now, I'm curious! Why not edit the question and add it?

Comment: added to the post

Comment: @aniket_777: OK, so that leads to a new question maybe. But please don't obfuscate all your multiplications just because of such a validation. You can implement a heuristic with a regular expression that just disallows `SELECT *` and `COUNT(*)` expressions (with some lenience with respect to case sensitivity and whitespace, etc.) or use a parser, but I would even doubt that this is reasonable *in general*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211628/discussion-between-aniket-777-and-lukas-eder).

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: This question here is about the asterisk. I appreciate your comment, but would you mind creating an issue rather than commenting here? That way, we can track things better...

Answer (score 3):

Oracle: **`*`** as string literal's delimeter:

```
SELECT q'*O'Brien*' AS name FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|  NAME   |
+---------+
| O'Brien |
+---------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c22de5c056b08e8ac4f48078271bd4b0)**

---

Hive: [REGEX Column Specification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select):

```
SELECT `commonPrefix*` FROM table_name
```

---

`*` as field terminator for all kind of SQL dialects that support external tables and/or COPY operation.

---

Azure Synapse: `*` as placeholder

```
SELECT p.filepath(1) AS [year],
       p.filepath(2) AS [month],
       COUNT_BIG(*)  AS cnt
FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'https://<sth>.windows.net/some_name/pyear=*/pmonth=*/*.parquet'
   ,FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
) AS p
WHERE p.filepath(1) IN ('2018','2019','2020');
```

---

SQL Server [compound operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/compound-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): `@var *= x` syntax as syntactic sugar for `@var = @var * x`

```
DECLARE @var INT = 1;
SELECT @var *= 2;
SELECT @var;
-- 2
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a471a869f74fe9cd1a9824770851c0f2)**

---

**EDIT:**

> "I've got a program which accepts SQL query and store it in DB. Before storing, it does a validation not allow to create select * and Count(*) queries. Other than that it should allow all other queries. So that's the reason I want to know other scenarios where * is used so that I can whitelist them."

Banning `*` does not prevent user from grabbing all columns. Example

```
SELECT * FROM t;
<=>
TABLE t;
-- PostgreSQL, MySQL
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6ae76bf103b6edcdaf906b8cd49fc4ef)**

Answer (score 0):

It is used in sql-server for xml.  In the code below, aliasing the subquery as '[*]' means that COLUMN_NAME and DATA_TYPE xml nodes output on the same level as TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME.  Compare with naming the column '[cols]':

```
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    t.TABLE_NAME, 
    (
        SELECT 
            c.COLUMN_NAME,
            c.DATA_TYPE
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
        WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        FOR XML PATH(''), type
    ) [*] -- compare with [cols]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cmn%'
FOR XML PATH ('Record'), ROOT('Data')
```

Outputs:

```
<Data>
  <Record>
    <TABLE_SCHEMA>dbo</TABLE_SCHEMA>
    <TABLE_NAME>Table1</TABLE_NAME>
    <COLUMN_NAME>Col1</COLUMN_NAME>
    <DATA_TYPE>int</DATA_TYPE>
    <COLUMN_NAME>Col2</COLUMN_NAME>
    <DATA_TYPE>int</DATA_TYPE>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    ...
  </Record>
</Data>
```

As opposed to (using [cols]):

```
<Data>
  <Record>
    <TABLE_SCHEMA>dbo</TABLE_SCHEMA>
    <TABLE_NAME>Table1</TABLE_NAME>
    <cols>
      <COLUMN_NAME>Col1</COLUMN_NAME>
      <DATA_TYPE>int</DATA_TYPE>
      <COLUMN_NAME>Col2</COLUMN_NAME>
      <DATA_TYPE>int</DATA_TYPE>
    </cols>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    ...
  </Record>
</Data>
```